# Is there something I'm doing wrong when trying to install next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to set up nextjs for a project. I follow the exact step by step instructions on their website, but cannot even get past the installation stage. The terminal shows quite a few errors about installing the npm packages.

Step by step instructions from the nextjs website.

npm install --save next react react-dom

After installation(which throws errors for me), I should be able to populate the pages/index.js file in my directory with export default () => Welcome to next.js!, and apparently I should be able to open localhost:3000 and everything should be fully functioning after npm run dev, but instead I get a localhost refused to connect message.

Comment: Please post your error stack trace

Comment: "The terminal shows quite a few errors". Pretty hard to tell you what's wrong without seeing the errors

Answer (score 0):

Why are you expecting "everything should be fully functioning after npm run dev" when you have received "a few errors"?

Most of the time when you receive errors when install npm packages, try deleting the whole `node_modules` folder and try again.

If that is the problem of `npm`, try upgrading `npm`

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```